# Help with python list-comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

A simplified version of my problem:

I have a list comprehension that i use to set bitflags on a two dimensional list so:

```
s = FLAG1 | FLAG2 | FLAG3
[[c.set_state(s) for c in row] for row in self.__map]
```

All set_state does is:

```
self.state |= f
```

This works fine but I have to have this function "set_state" in every cell in __map. Every cell in __map has a .state so what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
[[c.state |= s for c in row] for row in self.map]
```

or

```
map(lambda c: c.state |= s, [c for c in row for row in self.__map])
```

Except that neither works (Syntax error). Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree with map/lamda but I would like to get rid on set_state. And perhaps know why assignment does not work in the list-comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're using the wrong tool. A list comprehension returns a completely new value, so you might be able to do this:

```
self.__map = [[c.state | s for c in row] for row in self.__map]
```

But my instinct is that you should just be using two for loops:

```
for row in self.__map:
    for c in row:
        c.state |= s
```

In a list comprehension, the result has to be an expression. That's because your double comprehension is just sugar for this:

```
list1 = []
for row in self.__map:
    list2 = []
    for c in row:
        list2.append(c.state | s)
    list1.append(list2)
self.__map = list1
```

It makes no sense to say

```
        list2.append(c.state |= s)
```

Because the innermost expression has to return something to be appended to `list2`.

Basically, the list comprehensions make a complete new copy of self.__map each time you update the flags. If that's what you want, then  go with it. But I suspect you just want to change the existing map. In that case, use the double `for` loops.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehensions are for creating lists. You don't seem to care about the actual lists you are making, so you should just use a `for` statement, like so:

```
for row in self.__map:
    for c in row:
        c.state |= s
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a list comprehension, since you're modifying your data in-place, not creating a new list.

Do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) function:

```
setattr(c, "state", s)
```

And then read up on [Statementless Python](http://www.pick.ucam.org/~ptc24/yvfc.html).

Answer (score 0):

In python assignments are statements, not expressions which are only allowed in [lambdas](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) and list comprehension.